# QGIS Filters and Queries

Tags: qgis, query, filter

In QGIS is there a way to filter a layer using the Query Builder to show all values which include a particular phrase.  For example I have a list of organisations and I want to filter all those which include the word Wales.  I can do this using the attribute table but not in the map view so that the map just shows these selected features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "LIKE" with percentages.

In my shapefile of countries I can select any country with a name like "This and that" with:

```
"CNTRY_NAME" LIKE '% and %'
```

this selects only "Bosnia and Herzegovina". If I remove the spaces:

```
"CNTRY_NAME" LIKE '%and%'
```

I get Iceland, England and all the others with "and" in them.

That all works for shapefiles - the help for the query builder mentions that the syntax and behaviour may depend on your data source.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you so much Spacedman!!

Comment: Could you tick the little tick next to my answer to show that this question has now been answered?